# jquery inline edit get checkbox value depending on row clicked on

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to make an inline edit for my `wp_list_table` in `wordpress`, but I've hit a brick wall.

The issue is each elemement/td is made up off 2 class column example:

```
<td class="name column-name" contenteditable="true">
```

That's not enugh for me to make an inline edit. Hence, I turned towards the checkbox instead where they are built up as such:

```
<th class="check-column" scope="row">
<input type="checkbox" value="1976" name="movie[]">
```

Now the value being the unique id of my table that's what I need for my inline edit but I don't know how to store the value properly as I got 30+ rows but have to deal with classes.

I got as far as this,

```
var id_val = $("input[name='movie[]']:checkbox").val();
```

But it's useless cause it will always just get the id of the 1st row.

EDIT:
The html code:

```
<tr>
<th class="check-column" scope="row">
<input type="checkbox" value="1976" name="movie[]">
</th>
<td class="name column-name" contenteditable="true">Alexander Lausten</td>
<td class="datec column-datec" contenteditable="true">2015-06-09</td>
<td class="start column-start" contenteditable="true">12:00:00</td>
<td class="slut column-slut" contenteditable="true">23:00:00</td>
<td class="pause column-pause" contenteditable="true">0.50</td>
<td class="egenb column-egenb" contenteditable="true">130.00</td>
<td class="betaling column-betaling" contenteditable="true">3076.60</td>
</tr>
```

That's the markup of each row in the table.

Edit:
i need someway to solo out the checkbox value on my table. 
example: if i press on the name column on row 2 then i need it to grab the value on checkbox on row 2 without having to check the box

This ended up being my solution.

first i added a unique id for each tr with this code
        $(function() { 
     $('.wp-list-table tr').each(function(i) {

```
    $(this).attr('id', 'row'+(i-1));
    i++;
});
```

then i catch tr id with this

```
  var trid;
        $('.wp-list-table tr').click(function() {
       trid = $(this).attr('id');  

  });
```

then i grap the value of the checkbox with this:

```
var id = $( "tr#" + trid + " th.check-column input[name='movie[]']:checkbox").val();
```

Comment: Show us your html code to get a better view

Comment: Get some jsfiddle links

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly than you need something like this:

```
$("input[name='movie[]']:checkbox").click( function() {
    console.log($(this).val());    
});
```

Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/7z8a88yt/1/

See updated JSFiddle based on your comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7z8a88yt/3/

Comment: no i need someway to solo out the required checkbox value on my table.
example: if i press on the name column on row 2 then i need it to grab the value on checkbox on row 2 without having to check the box

Answer (score 0):

Use name="movie"

```
<tr>
<th class="check-column" scope="row">
<input type="checkbox" value="1976" name="movie">
</th>
<td class="name column-name" contenteditable="true">Alexander Lausten</td>
<td class="datec column-datec" contenteditable="true">2015-06-09</td>
<td class="start column-start" contenteditable="true">12:00:00</td>
<td class="slut column-slut" contenteditable="true">23:00:00</td>
<td class="pause column-pause" contenteditable="true">0.50</td>
<td class="egenb column-egenb" contenteditable="true">130.00</td>
<td class="betaling column-betaling" contenteditable="true">3076.60</td>
</tr>
```

Try This to get all IDs in array

```
var ids=[];
$("input[name='movie']").each(function(){
 ids.push($(this).val());
});
```

To make all the fields editable

```
$("input[name='movie']").each(function(){
 $(this).click(function(){
  var row=$(this).parent().parent();
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
   row.find('[contenteditable="true"]').each(function(){
   var inputFld=$('<input type="text" />');
   inputFld.val($(this).text());
   $(this).html(inputFld);
   });
  }else{
   row.find('[contenteditable="true"]').each(function(){
   var val=$(this).find('input').val();  
   $(this).html(val);
   });
  }
 })
});
```